# Writing domain and range using set notation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have the following math problem from my Number Theory class:

Let $D=\{1,2,3\}$ and $R=\{1,3,5\}$. Explicitly write out the set $D \times R$. Let $f:D \to R$ be a function defined by $f(x)=ax+b$ where $f(1)=1$, $f(2)=3$, and $f(3)=5$. What must be the values of $a$ and $b$? Finally, explicitly write out the relation $f$ represents, and verify that it is indeed a subset of $D \times R$.

For the set $D \times R$, I came up with $\{(1,1),(1,3),(1,5),(2,1),(2,3),(2,5),(3,1),(3,3),(3,5)\}$.
For the values of $a$ and $b$, I came up with $a=2$ and $b=-1$, which gives me a function of $f(x)=2x-1$.

When it comes to writing the relation in set notation, I'm confused. Should I be writing the relation in regards to the function, or should it be regarding the relation with respect to the sets? If I'm only looking at the function, would that make the answer $f=\{(x, 2x-1)| x\in \mathbb R \}$?

Comment: Written that way, $f$ is not a subset of $D \times R$, because for $x= \dfrac 1 2$ we can compute $f(\dfrac 1 2)=0$ but $\dfrac 1 2 \notin D$ and $0 \notin R$.

Comment: We must have something like: $f = \{ (x,y) \mid x \in D \text { and } y= 2x-1  \}$.

Comment: $f=\{(x,2x-1): x\in D\}=\{(1,1),(2,3),(3,5)\}$. For any function $g$ we have $g=\{(x,g(x)):x\in dom(g)\}.$